# Why Bitmap saves to PNG

Tags: c#

I have Bitmap object in my application. Why `Save()` method saves to `PNG` format file instead of `BMP`?

```
Bitmap currentImmage;
...
currentImmage.Save("image.bmp");
```

Comment: You can specify the format by passing a second parameter `ImageFormat.Bmp`.

Comment: Congratulations on your 800th question. For the next one, could you read [ask] and try researching first, for example by reading the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation

[Save(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_)

> **If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable
>   Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used**. When you use the Save method
>   to save a graphic image as a Windows Metafile Format (WMF) or Enhanced
>   Metafile Format (EMF) file, the resulting file is saved as a Portable
>   Network Graphics (PNG) file. This behavior occurs because the GDI+
>   component of the .NET Framework does not have an encoder that you can
>   use to save files as .wmf or .emf files.

Use instead

[Save(String, ImageFormat)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_)

> Saves this Image to the specified file in the specified format.

[ImageFormat Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Specifies the file format of the image.

**Example**

```
currentImmage.Save("image.bmp",ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft Docs on [`Bitmap.Save(string)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_):

> **If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used.** When you use the Save method to save a graphic image as a Windows Metafile Format (WMF) or Enhanced Metafile Format (EMF) file, the resulting file is saved as a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file. This behavior occurs because the GDI+ component of the .NET Framework does not have an encoder that you can use to save files as .wmf or .emf files.

I believe you want to use `Bitmap.Save(String, ImageFormat)` to save to a different format.